# C# Call Tree or Call Sequence per Method

Tags: c#

Our project is being written in C# and there is an ancient code requirement (that I would like to automate) where: "A called unit is listed in a module’s header each time it is called. The calls are listed in order of occurrence. This remains true even if the sequence is repeated.

- All called units must be listed
- One listing for every call
- In the order of occurrence"

Therefore I'm looking for a tool that will generate a (text) "Call Tree" for each method within a C# source file (".cs").  Where a "Call Tree" is a static (non-runtime) tree which shows the calling structure of a method. It shows every call to other methods/classes that each method displays it in an indented tree format.

Example:

```
VSystem.getInfo()
VSystem.getInfo()
VSystem.getInfo()
   SystemView()
   SystemView()
   SystemView()
     BView()
VSystem.getInfo()
   CView()
VSystem.getInfo()
   CView()
VSystem.getInfo()
   BtView()
VSystem.getInfo()
```

I've looked at some popular tools such as "CLR Profiler", "ReSharper", "NDepend", and ".NET Reflector", however these all focus on runtime diagnostics.  And other tools such as the open source [SequenceViz](http://sequenceviz.codeplex.com/) tools generate the call trees by reverse engineering the assemblies rather than parsing the C# source files ("*.cs").  I also found [this open source Call Tree program](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32118/Call-tree-for-C-programs) by Loius T Klauder Jr., however it uses regular expressions to parse the C# code that do not seem to work for my code-base.

Can anyone recommend any other tools that would generate a "Call Tree" as defined above?

Comment: Take a look at Roslyn
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx

Comment: How will the tree handle conditional statements?

Comment: Maybe you should post some code samples from you source files and the expected output for them.